# Ports and security in URL

Tags: node.js, socket.io, port

I'm going to use socket.io on nodeJs in order to be able to send messages from my server to my client.

Node runs on a separate port from what I normally use for my hosting. Is there any safety risk in using the port number in the url in production? For example, I'm directing users to domain.tld:0000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no more security risks in exposing node.js on another port than running node.js itself exposed to the internet.